# oversampling some classes from time series data

Tags: python, classification, oversampling

For some classification needs. I have multivariate time series data composed from 4 stelite images in form of (145521 pixels, 4 dates, 2 bands)
I made a classification with tempCNN to classify the data into 5 classes. However there is a big gap between the class 1,2 with 500 samples and 4,5 with 1452485 samples.

I' am wondering if there is a method that help me oversamling the two first classes to make my dataset more adequate for classification.

Answer (score 2):

actually there is a lib in python for that "imbalanced-learn" (although u can do it manually) .

you can check the docs it's very easy to use

Comment: thank you very much, However i am afraid that it is not suitable for time series processing

Comment: in this case i suggest you do it manually ( i mean create an algorithm with some conditions , arrays and for loops to accomplish this task).